# Connection between Netlify and AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netlify

I have a react.js frontend app deployed on netlify and a node.js backend deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk. How do I establish a connection between my frontend and backend. It is showing that i need to establish api endpoints.How to establish api endpoints and also where to establish endpoints i.e whether to establish them in my react frontend or Node Backend?

I have tried using netlify functions & AWS Lambda but couldn't figure it out.